# how can i generate exe from windows service file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I had created a Lib Project with a class inherits ServiceBase but when I run the solution i'm not getting the EXE file?

```
public class Scheduler : ServiceBase
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] {new Scheduler()};
        Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that your project type is `Windows Application`, which is recommended for windows services.

What you did is not enough in order to install and start your service. You cannot yet install your service. You have to provide an installer class which can then be used by `InstallUtil` to register your service.

You can see an example of this in the [`ServiceProcessInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.aspx) class documentation.

After that, build your service again and install it by running in a command window the following:

```
"%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" "YourServiceExeName.exe"
```

You will then be able to see your service in the services snap-in.

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating a project of type **Windows Service** ? and the installation part is already mentioned by the coon, but you need all the service exe path, not juste the service name.

Good luck